# How to programmatically add stylable attribute to a view?

Tags: android, kotlin, declare-styleable

I have a custom button with some stylable attributes

```
<declare-styleable name="MBButton">
    <attr name="button_type_accessible" format="enum">
        <enum name="primary" value="0" />
        <enum name="secondary" value="1" />
        <enum name="secondary_alternative" value="2" />
        <enum name="ghost" value="3" />
        <enum name="ghost_alternative" value="4" />
        <enum name="action" value="5" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="is_medium_size_accessible" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="is_small_size_accessible" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="make_accessible_button" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I need to create this button programmatically and set some of this attributes. I guess to do this I should set this info in the AttributeSet and use it when I create the button. But I cannot make it work in Kotlin.

This is the constructor of my custom button

```
class CustomButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context,
attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.mbButtonSecondaryStyle
)
```

Comment: Can you show your init block, where you are applying these attributes to your layout?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/create-view#addprop you can't programmatically set attributes, but instead you should define fields/getters/setters for your attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make functions in your `CustomButton` class as follow

```
class CustomButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 
    R.attr.mbButtonSecondaryStyle
) {

    init{
        ...
    }

    fun setAccessibleButton(text: String) {
        binding.textView.text.setText(text)
    }
}
```

Suppose you create function for `make_accessible_button` as follow:

Do this same for each attribute and code the functionality as you want.